# AngularJS Update input with two models with onSubmit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the following.

Directive 1 -> Displays in the users form
Directive 2 -> Only updates when the user presses the submit button.

Examplesnippet:

```
<h2>{{directive1}}</h2> <!-- This is seen by the user when he changes directive 1 !-->
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="directive1" name="input" placeholder="This is the primary input (this needs to be updated when the form is used by the user. ">
<h3>{{directive2}}</h3> <!-- This should only be changed when the user presses the submit button on the form ng-model-options: {onUpdate: 'submit'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your modified example. `directive1` updates on user input. `directive2` updates on <kbd>Enter</kbd>. **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6773/)**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.directive1 = "stackoverflow";
    $scope.directive2 = "submit your text";
    $scope.myFunc = function () {
        $scope.directive2 = $scope.directive1;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h2>{{directive1}}</h2>
<form ng-submit="myFunc()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="directive1" name="input" placeholder="">
</form>
<h3>{{directive2}}</h3> 
</div>
```